# Failed to load YAML using PyYaml?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Has anyone ever found an error like this?

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\yaml\parser.py", line 439, in parse_block_mapping_key
"expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, token.start_mark)

ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "a.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "a.yml", line 224, column 2
```

I found it when I tried to load a YAML file using PyYaml.  I googled it, but I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, I didn't get a valid YAML file. At first, I thought my code was wrong, but, after I checked the [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) 
it returned the same output. Assuming that website is right, the YAML file is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Line number in error can be misleading. Look at the entire section (indentation) that most likely starts on reported line number.

In my case it was a typo in file. I had:

`key5:
  sub1: 234
  sub2: 9879
  sub3: "string in quotes"asdf
  sub4: "another string in quotes"`

The parser obviously didnt like **asdf** outside quotes for **sub3** value however  line number and column in error pointed to the first entry in indentation (sub1) instead sub3 where the error actually was.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but for me it was an indentation issue(!)